# OpenGL: try to draw lines using VBO(vertex buffer object), it doesn't display

Tags: c, opengl, vbo, vertex-buffer-objects

I try to switch my openGL code from using display list to using VBO.
In the code, I tried to draw a green-grid floor, which is composed by green lines in parallel with x-axis and green lines in parallel with z-axis.
But when the program runs, floor doesn't display. And I can't find where goes wrong.

Here is my code initialize VBO of floor:

```
//**********************************
//defined in head of my source code
struct BufferVBO1
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
};
struct IdVBO
{
    GLuint id;
    size_t bufsiz;
};
IdVBO vboGround;
//**************************************
glGenBuffers(1, &vboGround.id);
int groundSiz1 = ( (floorEdge_x_max-floorEdge_x_min)/(5*LENGTH_UNIT)+1 )*2 ;
int groundSiz2 = ( (floorEdge_z_max-floorEdge_z_min)/(5*LENGTH_UNIT)+1 )*2 ;
vboGround.bufsiz = groundSiz1+groundSiz2 ;
BufferVBO1 *groundBuf = new BufferVBO1 [vboGround.bufsiz];
for(int i=0, idx=0; idx<groundSiz1; ++i)
{
    groundBuf[idx].x = floorEdge_x_min+i*5*LENGTH_UNIT;
    groundBuf[idx].y = 0;
    groundBuf[idx].z = floorEdge_z_min;
    groundBuf[idx].r = 75/255.0;
    groundBuf[idx].g = 1.0;
    groundBuf[idx].b = 63/255.0;
    ++idx;

    groundBuf[idx].x = floorEdge_x_min+i*5*LENGTH_UNIT;
    groundBuf[idx].y = 0;
    groundBuf[idx].z = floorEdge_z_max;
    groundBuf[idx].r = 75/255.0;
    groundBuf[idx].g = 1.0;
    groundBuf[idx].b = 63/255.0;
    ++idx;
}
for(int i=0, idx=groundSiz1; idx<vboGround.bufsiz; ++i)
{
    groundBuf[idx].x = floorEdge_x_min;
    groundBuf[idx].y = 0;
    groundBuf[idx].z = floorEdge_z_min+i*5*LENGTH_UNIT;
    groundBuf[idx].r = 75/255.0;
    groundBuf[idx].g = 1.0;
    groundBuf[idx].b = 63/255.0;
    ++idx;

    groundBuf[idx].x = floorEdge_x_max;
    groundBuf[idx].y = 0;
    groundBuf[idx].z = floorEdge_z_min+i*5*LENGTH_UNIT;
    groundBuf[idx].r = 75/255.0;
    groundBuf[idx].g = 1.0;
    groundBuf[idx].b = 63/255.0;
    ++idx;
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboGround.id);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(BufferVBO1)*vboGround.bufsiz, groundBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
delete [] groundBuf ;
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Here is the code to display:

```
 glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboGround.id);
 glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
 glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(BufferVBO1), (void*)0);
 glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 glColorPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(BufferVBO1), (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*3) );
 for(int i=0; i<vboGround.bufsiz; i+=2)
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE, i, 2);
 glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
 glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
 glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

I've tried to draw a simple GL_QUADS floor using VBO, and it works! But when I tried to draw green-grid floor, it doesn't display.

Tell me where is the problem.

Comment: Not sure if this is your only problem, but the size passed to `glBufferData()` is in bytes. It looks like you're passing the number of vertices instead.

Comment: thank u for replying. This is a mistake. I changed `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboGround.bufsiz, groundBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` to `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(BufferVBO1)*vboGround.bufsiz, groundBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`It still not works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `glDrawArrays()` here is invalid:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE, i, 2);
```

`GL_LINE` is not a valid primitive type. You need to use `GL_LINES`:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, i, 2);
```

`GL_LINE` may look very similar, but it's one of the possible arguments for `glPolygonMode()`.

You should always call `glGetError()` when your OpenGL call does not behave as expected. In this case, it should have returned `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.

BTW, you can draw all the lines in a single `glDrawArrays()` call, instead of using a loop:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vboGround.bufsize);
```